# Gem install fails on windows. mkmf.log cannot find -lX11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rmagick

I am trying to install rmagick gem on for my rails framework.
I have installed imagemagick and set lib and include path in system variables

But when installing gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8"' i still get errors.

gem command

```
C:\sites\redmine> gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8"'
gem.bat : ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
At line:1 char:4
+ gem <<<<  install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6
.7.9-Q8"'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR:  While e...:InvalidOption) 
   :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    invalid option: --with-opt-dir=c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8
```

mkmf.log file says

```
assert_minimum_ruby_version!: checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib -L.    -lCORE_RL_magick_ -lX11  -lmsvcrt-ruby210  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
c:/railsinstaller/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lCORE_RL_magick_
c:/railsinstaller/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lX11
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

From log it is clear that devkit is not able to locate ImageMagick
But i have set it PATH = C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q8

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered developing with nitrous io?  Developing rails in windows is much harder because there are a lot of errors you have to deal with that others don't and there's not a whole lot of documentation/support.  Most answers boil down to something like "windows and rails don't mix".

Comment: yes this seems to be final alternative if I fail to setup it up this week. nitrous io was little slower so i was avoiding it,